# Rounding to greater integer c

Tags: c

i want to know the method to round off a float value to next largest integer....ex- 12.1   to  13   and 12.9 to 13  or  45.7 to 46  etc  always the next int

Comment: Add 1,0 and round it down.

Comment: Or if you happen to have math.h included, just use ceil(x).

Comment: will it convert float to integer value...or float to float..?

Comment: Just cast it to an int after... int result = (int)ceil(x);

Comment: Don't use the add-one-and-cast-to-int method some people are suggesting unless you also want to bump up floats that already represent an integer value, eg. 12.0 --> 13.  Of course, you can't really distinguish between a number with no fractional part and one where the fractional part is too small to represent, so nothing will be perfect...

Comment: What results do you expect with whole number values like `1.0f, 2.0f, ...`?  When you say "largest" and the input is negative, do you want the result to be towards -infinity or + infinity?  Example: what should be the result of `-1.1f`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following method:

```
int roundedOffValue(float value) //rounded off value will be an integer that can be caught in float
{
    return ceil(value);
}
```

Do not forget to include the `math.h` library.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple function like this.

```
int roundFloatToUpper(float f)
{
    if (f < 0)
         return ((int)(f))
    else
         return ((int)(f + 1)
}
```

i think that using math.h is overkill for something like that.

Comment: On what basis do you think `math.h` is overkill?

Comment: Code does not compile.  Depending on interpretation of what `roundFloatToUpper(f)` should do when `f` is a whole number, algorithm  fails for values like `-1.0, -2.0f ...` or `1.0, 2.0f ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can add 1 to your value and then cast into `int`. It also works with negative numbers.

```
float f = 12.1;
float temp = f + ((f < 0) ? 0 : 1);
int result = (int)temp;// 13
```

Comment: Does this work for negative numbers though? (int)(-12.1 + 1) = (int)(-11.1) = -11. Where you would want -12. Casting to int does not round down, it just truncates the decimals.

Comment: No, the next larger value of a négative number as -11.6 is -11 not -12.

Comment: But the next larger value of a negative number as -12.1 is -12 and not -11 as I think your method will result in.

Comment: Fails for values just under `0.5, 1.0, 2.0, ...` as in `0.9999999404 + 1` --> `2.0f`.  The sum saved in `temp` was rounded up before `int` truncation.